# firefox marionette bypass security exception

Tags: selenium, webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am using Marionette / Geckodriver v9.0 for mac with selenium jar 2.53.1.
When it opens firefox 47 I'm getting the error that "Your connection is not secure".
The code I'm using to create the driver is:

```
  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = null; 
  firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
  firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
  firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

  DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  capability.setCapability("marionette", true);
  capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
  capability.setCapability("handlesAlerts", true);
  return new MarionetteDriver(capability);
```

So, how do I get it to add my website as an exception or turn off the check? Or is it a feature that Marionette hasn't implemented yet?

Comment: Can you post the full error or screenshot of the error

Comment: Yes, its a known issue as of today. You need to provide a self signed certificate in the meanwhile https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196

Comment: The error I get in FF is that the owner of the certifcate has configured the website improperly.

Comment: When I open the advanced it adds that the issuer certificate is unknown. error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER. Even though at this time I accept the certificate as an exception, the driver has thrown an error. I don't run into this problem when I open the site normally.

Comment: In my opinion this situation is infuriating. People often use Selenium to test sites under development; why should Mozilla assume these sites have signed certs? Chromedriver doesn't have this problem and, prior to Marionette, neither did Firefox's driver.

Why do people insist on 'fixing' what's not broken!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox: 50.1.0
Gecko Driver: 0.13 (install nuget package: Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver.0.13.0)

Firstly, open a standard Firefox browser, and make sure the default Firefox profile has added the unsecured site into the certificate exception list.
C# code as follows:

```
FirefoxProfileManager fpManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();

var profiles = fpManager.ExistingProfiles;
var defaultProfile = fpManager.GetProfile(profiles.First());

driver = new FirefoxDriver(defaultProfile);
```

Comment: Be warned that with this, you won't be able to run another instance of Firefox at the same time (whether manual or marionette) because the profile is in use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nightly build of firefox of developer edition for now. It will not work on the current version.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196

Comment: Welp, looks like it's not working for me there either, despite what the thread says. I'll update if I get it working.

Comment: any idea whether it's working I'm seeing the bug is resolved @J_01